# $ is not defined in sugarcrm

Tags: javascript, php, linux, sugarcrm

Before you mark the question as duplicate, read it well. The problem is when I changed the server to another do not load scripts well. On other servers there is no problem. I need to know that it must be enabled or modified on the server for the sugarcrm to work.

I changed from server to a more modern one (from hivelocity to a2hosting), I made a backup of all the crm information and copied it to the new server and I gave the necessary permissions as it appears in this [link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/%20Knowledge_Base%20/%20Platform_Management%20/%20Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux%20/%20index.html) or the basics permissions to fix the interface and css.

But the problem was that it generates this error

"Uncaught ReferenceError

> : $ is not defined".

I have been doing this many times and installed many sugarcrm and this is the first time I have this error.

[image: Image error]

To make sure and rule out another problem, I did the same copy of information and processes to a godaddy server and it worked perfectly.

Could you help me?

Comment: $ not defined is missing jQuery. Press F12 and look in the network tab to see why.

Comment: you have a missing jquery reference

Comment: You're missing jquery reference. If not then try using ` /*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/ ` this in your `js` file.

Comment: In the link "Image error" You can look at the error. 
And the missing jquery reference, is only in this server, because I copied same data in other server and work fine.

Comment: Where is jQuery being loaded? *Is* it being loaded? Have you checked the network tab?

Comment: In the network tab does not display the jquery load. What I do not understand is because it does not load any javascript file on this server.

Comment: The trouble was php version server and support to crm. Thanks!

Comment: Hello everyone,
The problem was the php version. My server had php 6 and sugarcrm does not support versions greater than 5.6. I downloaded it and it worked correctly.

Thank you very much