# $ is not defined in sugarcrm and it is not a duplicate

Tags: jquery, linux, server, sugarcrm

The problem is when I changed the server to another do not load scripts well. On other servers there is no problem. I need to know that it must be enabled or modified on the server for the SugarCRM to work.

I changed from server to a more modern one (from hivelocity to a2hosting), I made a backup of all the crm information and copied it to the new server and I gave the necessary permissions as it appears in this [link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/%20Knowledge_Base%20/%20Platform_Management%20/%20Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux%20/%20index.html) or the basics permissions to fix the interface and css.

But the problem was that it generates this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I have been doing this many times and installed many sugarcrm and this is the first time I have this error.

[Image error](http://buenaeducacion.co/Imagen1.png)

To make sure and rule out another problem, I did the same copy of information and processes to a godaddy server and it worked perfectly.

Could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ is not defined in sugarcrm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061310/is-not-defined-in-sugarcrm)

Comment: 1. Did you switch from a non-ssl host to an ssl host (or vice-versa)? 2. Did you change URLs and neglect to change the `config.php` file to the new `site_url` param? 3. Did your URL change to a subdirectory or a subdirectory of a different name (e.g. `host:port/one` to `host:port/two`)?

Comment: The two servers are ssl. The domain was targeted to new server, the domain or sub directories are same. The config.php was modified for set new database.

Comment: The trouble was php version server and support to crm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the php version. My server had php 6 and sugarcrm does not support versions greater than 5.6. I downloaded it and it worked correctly.

Thank you very much